# Android asmack Chat client for XMPP server

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

I am trying to build an Android chat client using [asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) library, and an XMPP server like [openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/).
 So can anybody provide me with some links to tutorials or code snippets for my client programm.

Comment: try http://www.google.com it will help you more than http://www.stackoverflow.com. Its not a problem. make some effort.!!!

Comment: Try this xmpp-tutorials.blogspot.com.br –

Comment: @akshay u got any thing?

Answer (score 5):

Read their own documentation: [SMACK DOCS](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can start with  [Xabber](https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android) android   client.